# How do I move a link to a folder in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list of external link items that I have created underneath a standard team site on our SharePoint 2010 portal. I then created a number of folders to help categorise the links, but can't find any way of moving those links into the folders I created.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Found a solution via Site Settings > Site Content and Structure, which lets you move items to folders, however, I'd like to know if end users creating links without access to this section can do the same from the links page.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is another way to do this.  You could use Datasheet mode to cut/paste the link to a new folder, but that's just as cumbersome as Content and Structure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest let end users use the SharePoint designer to do this. SharePoint designer is free to download from Microsoft's website and it's a must-have tool to use SharePoint.

Comment: How would I go about this? When I edit the links list in Designer, I only see admin options on the list itself, or the ability to move the pages that make up the list, not the items it contains.

Comment: Sorry, I think I just misunderstood your question! And you are right, we can't move items in SharePoint Designer. But as an alternate, the SP List Kits may help you: http://splistkit.codeplex.com/ .